# How to render pages without .html extension as html pages in Apache server

Tags: html, apache, server

I made a webpage that should load a html files into a iframe. When you click something, it appears in . Although all of my files are html documents with html tags, they don't have extensions. So in the iframe, it renders as plain text. How do i configure Apache server setting so that the default file extension is set to ".html" when the file doesn't have any extension? Does it have anything to do with .htaccess file?

It seems like I can hide file extensions by doing some trick in that file, but I'm trying to do the opposite (adding an extension). How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are using [an old version](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#defaulttype) of Apache:

```
DefaultType text/html
```

> DefaultType Directive
>
> MIME content-type that will be sent if the server cannot determine a type in any other way

For the [current version](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#defaulttype):

> Use the mime.types configuration file and the AddType to configure media type assignments via file extensions, or the ForceType directive to configure the media type for specific resources. Otherwise, the server will send the response without a Content-Type header field and the recipient may attempt to guess the media type.

So:

```
# force all files to be text/html:
<Location />
  ForceType text/html
</Location>
```

Comment: in which file should i do this? httpd.conf?

Comment: Possibly. I generally limit such changes to specific virtual name hosts (and have separate config files for each which get included in the main apache config).